# Use declared variables in a switch

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, switch-statement, case

I am using a switch to either `submit, delete, or cancel`. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but I can't access the values of any input that was submitted. I can echo them outside the switch and they work just fine.

Here is the Ajax:

```
function check_url(recieve_url, type) {
    if (recieve_url == undefined || recieve_url == null) {
        alert("recieve_url is not set!");
    }
    $.ajax({
        url : recieve_url,
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : "type="+type,
        success : function (result) {
            //alert(result['bg'] + result['message'] + result['caption'])

            myApp.alert(result['message'], result['title'], function () {
                if (result['redirect'] != null || result['redirect'] != undefined){
                    window.location = "<?php echo $this->url;?>"+result['redirect'];
                }
            });
                //myApp.alert(result['message'], result['title']);


        },
        error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            myApp.alert(xhr.responseText);
            myApp.alert(xhr.status);
            myApp.alert(thrownError);
        }
    })

}
```

And here is the PHP:

```
function EditSubmit($ID = ''){
    //get the case name to direct to
    $type = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["type"]));
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE id = :id";
    $arr  = array(":id" => $ID);
    $result = $this->database->DBQry($sql, $arr);
    $id = $result[0]['id'];
    $email = $result[0]['email'];
    $admin = $result[0]['admin'];
    $staff = $result[0]['staff'];
    $disabled = $result[0]['disabled'];
    $active = $result[0]['active'];
    $admin_check = isset($_POST['admin_check']);
    $address = isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : '';
    echo $address.' '.$admin_check;

    switch ($type) {
        case 'submit':
        if ($admin == 1){
            $response = array(
                'message' => 'Cannot edit an administrator',
                'title' => 'Error'
                );
        }else{
            $arr = array(":address" => $address, ":admin" => $admin_check, ":staff" => 1, ":disabled" => 1, ":active" => 1);
            $this->database->DBSet($arr,'staff',$whr = 'WHERE id = '.$ID);
            $response = array(
                'message' => 'active'.$address.' admin'.$_SESSION['qun'].' staff'.$staff_box.' disabled'.$disabled_box,
                'title' => 'Success',
                'redirect' => 'Staff/Edit'
                );
        }
        break;
        case 'delete':
        if ($admin == 1){
            $response = array(
                'message' => 'Cannot delete an administrator',
                'title' => 'Error'
                );
        }else{
            $this->database->DBDel('staff',$whr = 'WHERE ID = '.$ID);
            $response = array(
                'message' => 'Staff member deleted',
                'title' => 'Success',
                'redirect' => 'Staff/Edit'
                );
        }
        break;
        case 'cancel':
        $response = array(
            'message' => 'Nothing has been changed',
            'title' => 'Canceled',
            'redirect' => 'Staff/Edit'
            );
        break;
    }


    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

I'm able to `echo` them right before the switch. So I'm lost on why I can't use those inside the switch.

Comment: So the $type var in your PHP is actually getting a value?  Add a default case to your switch, too, to catch unexpected values

Comment: remove or comment the 'echo $address.' '.$admin_check;' for the ajax request

Comment: @miglio, that isn't going to solve anything, I can echo it when I access the Ajax URL. It doesn't allow the variables to be used inside the case.